# Sending variables between files with batch

Tags: batch

So i have 2 Bat files A and B.
A runs, now I use a command to start B.
Now A and B are running at the same time. 
And now I want to send my Variable C from A to B.
I tried Call but then it just opens B twice . 
Thanks for future answeres!
Edit* without additional files

Comment: Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here. If there is however, then [edit] and explain the real goal.

Comment: I think you will have to control the logic well in B and set an initial `set /p` from a file like shown in Sponge Bob's answer to a default when initially launched and add conditional logic in it to tell it to only take whatever action you want it to take `if not ["%var%"]==["%setVar%"]` and then if it does not equal that `setVar` to then so something and set the `setVar` to whatever you just ran and then starting checking the conditional logic from the value in the file until it changes again which A can do whenever. This is certainly possible that way working around the limitation in a way.

Comment: @DavidPostill I believe waitfor is a highly limited IPC .  At least between batch files. It may be an answer if this is a mistated question but in the way this has been asked it is not an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The setx command writes a variable into the registry and can be used if you want to use a variable globally for all batch files.

```
SETX VAR_C somevalue
```

Alternatively you could write the variable to a file and read it back into the other batch file ie;

Batch file A:

```
SET VAR_C=somevalue
ECHO %VAR_C% >%TMP%\var_c
```

Batch file B:

```
SET /P VAR_C=<%TMP%\var_c
ECHO %VAR_C%
```

Comment: Setx won't help with already running batches. A batch inherits the environment from the starting process and will not recognize meanwhile changes to the master environment.

Comment: I think you will have to control the logic well in B and set an initial `set /p` from a file like shown in Sponge Bob's answer to a default when initially launched and add conditional logic in it to tell it to only take whatever action you want it to take `if not ["%var%"]==["%setVar%"]` and then if it does not equal that `setVar` to then so something and set the `setVar` to whatever you just ran and then starting checking the conditional logic from the value in the file until it changes again which A can do whenever. This is certainly possible that way working around the limitation in a way.

Comment: The 'reg query' command can be used to read registry values once a batch file is already running.

Answer (score 0):

If you were not using the windows command prompt running a and b at the same time is impossible.  Even with the call command **a** is stop and **b** runs to completion return to **a** after the call command in true DOS.

When running in windows command prompt they are 2 entirely different processes and don't share memory, variables, or etc.

The way batch files work is they use %1 to %9

**shift** allows the use of 10 or more values by shifting everything down by 1 and losing the lowest value.

So inside of a.bat
call b.bat "scooby doo" "was" "here"

Now inside of b.bat

```
%1 = "scooby doo"
%2 = "was"
%3 = "here"
```

---

alternative

The **SET** command also exists

set C="scooby doo"

echo %c%

---

From the department of ugly,limited, and hacky

mkdir "\share"
mkdir "\share\c"
and then in batch file **a** you could create a file named whatever you want to share.

note: inside a batch file double percent symbols maybe be needed.

```
for  %i in ("c:\x\c\*.*"); do set c="%~ni"
```

However, you can't use the same special characters then, for example the period.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I have added an alternative.  However DOS is very limited in what it can do.  Depending on how **b** was started neither way is guaranteed to work.  Its best if **b** isn't started before hand then the variables will transition.  If **a** and **b** are started in 2 different windows command prompts they are entirely different processes and don't share any memory space.